# Maximising Performance Increases with Cython

Tags: c++, python, cython

I've been trying to code a graphical application that demonstrates machine learning for a project at university and I've been developing it in Python. Because Python's a pretty slow language, I was looking for ways to speed up run-time execution, and stumbled across Cython. I'm not very familiar with C / C++ yet, but I've tried statically typing as much of my code as possible (despite warnings that this can reduce readability / flexibility; this isn't my main concern at the moment).

However, I haven't really noticed any significant improvement of this implementation over just pure Python, and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions of how to speed it up. I'd be very happy with something like a 10x speed-up, though I'm not sure how realistic this is.

̶I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶f̶i̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶y̶e̶t̶  I've profiled my code and the results are linked below.

Because it's still a work in progress, the layout isn't great, but I've done some simple grouping of functions.

The source code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/jRb1Bq2y). The most relevent parts of the code are posted below.

.

Iterating through a given pad's memory:

```
cdef findBestApproximation(int padindex):
    cdef double last_collision_x
    cdef double last_collision_y
    cdef double last_collision_i_angle
    cdef double last_collision_i_speed
    cdef double last_collision_f_angle
    cdef double last_collision_f_speed
    cdef double x_divergence
    cdef double y_divergenve
    cdef double f_angular_divergence
    cdef double divergence

    printData("FINDING APPROXIMATION FOR PAD %s...\n" % padindex)
    pad = Pads.padlist[padindex]
    memory = pad.memory
    ball = Balls.ball
    if not memory:
        approximation = getPadMidpoint(padindex)
        return approximation

    collision_data = getCollisionData()
    (last_collision_x, last_collision_y, last_collision_i_angle,
     last_collision_i_speed, last_collision_f_angle,
     last_collision_f_speed) = collision_data

    best_approx = 0
    strictness_coef = 1.03

    for memory_tuple in memory:
        (x_miss, y_miss, x_collision, y_collision, _, _, f_angle, _) = memory_tuple.getData()
        (divergence, x_divergence, y_divergence, f_angular_divergence) = calculateDivergence(memory_tuple, collision_data)

        divergence = x_divergence + y_divergence + f_angular_divergence

        approximation = (divergence, x_miss, y_miss)

        printData("\n\nPAD: %s" % padindex)
        printData("\nLAST COLLISION (X) = %s, CONSIDERED CASE (X) = %s" % (last_collision_x, x_collision))
        printData("pos_x DIVERGENCE: %s" % x_divergence)

        printData("\nLAST COLLISION (Y) = %s, CONSIDERED CASE (Y) = %s" % (last_collision_y, y_collision))
        printData("pos_y DIVERGENCE: %s" % y_divergence)

        printData("\nLAST COLLISION (fAngle) = %s, CONSIDERED CASE (fAngle) = %s" % (last_collision_f_angle, f_angle))
        printData("FINAL ANGLE DIVERGENCE: %s" % f_angular_divergence)

        printData("\nTOTAL DIVERGENCE: %s\n\n" % divergence)

        if not best_approx:
            best_approx = approximation
        else:
            (least_divergence, _, _) = best_approx 
            if divergence < least_divergence:
                best_approx = approximation

    (_, pos_x, pos_y) = best_approx
    approximation = (pos_x, pos_y)
    return approximation
```

.

Calculating and attributing a score to a particular past event stored in  the pad's memory:

```
cdef calculateDivergence(memory_tuple, collision_data):
    cdef double pos_x_dif
    cdef double pos_y_dif
    cdef double i_angle_dif
    cdef double i_speed_dif
    cdef double f_angle_dif
    cdef double f_speed_dif

    cdef double max_x_difference
    cdef double max_y_difference
    cdef double max_angular_difference

    cdef double x_divergence
    cdef double y_divergence
    cdef double f_angular_divergence
    cdef double total_divergence

    (last_collision_x, last_collision_y, last_collision_i_angle,
     last_collision_i_speed, last_collision_f_angle,
     last_collision_f_speed) = collision_data

    (x_miss, y_miss, x_collision, y_collision,
     i_angle, i_speed, f_angle, f_speed      ) = memory_tuple.getData()

    pos_x_dif   = abs(x_collision - last_collision_x)
    pos_y_dif   = abs(y_collision - last_collision_y)
    i_angle_dif = getAngleDifference(i_angle, last_collision_i_angle)
    i_speed_dif = abs(i_speed - last_collision_i_speed)
    f_angle_dif = getAngleDifference(f_angle, last_collision_f_angle)
    f_speed_dif = abs(f_speed - last_collision_f_speed)

    max_x_difference       = window_width
    max_y_difference       = window_height
    max_angular_difference = 180

    x_divergence         = 100 * pos_x_dif   / max_x_difference
    y_divergence         = 100 * pos_y_dif   / max_y_difference
    f_angular_divergence = 100 * f_angle_dif / max_angular_difference

    #Apply weights.
    x_divergence         *= WeightData.current_weight
    y_divergence         *= WeightData.current_weight
    f_angular_divergence *= (1 - WeightData.current_weight)

    total_divergence = x_divergence + y_divergence + f_angular_divergence

    divergence_data = (total_divergence, x_divergence, y_divergence, f_angular_divergence)
    return divergence_data
```

EDIT: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/bCfjUVCg) the results of profiling the code. DrawSettingsMenu() is one  of the worst but it can be ignored (by default the settings menu is not displayed). Any "Initialise..." functions can be ignored too.

Comment: My first suggestion would TEST where your code is slow, and dont guess. So you know X function takes Y time in "total".

Comment: Or just try `pypy`, which works with pure Python code. It does not work for all of Python, but if it works for your application, you are golden.

Comment: It seems that this is a question better asked at CodeReview

Comment: @EKS, the code is now profiled, I'll just have to spend time analysing it.

Comment: @MatthieuM., I had a look at PyPy but it only seems to support Python 2.7 right now. It still sounds interesting though.

Answer (score 5):

You should first profile your code and see what need to be optimized.
Then you should try to optimize the algorithm as mush as you can.
If you identify a function that is too slow in Python, you can try to statically type it using Cython, but you will get better performances by writing it in C and calling it from Cython. But be sure your code behave correctly before optimizing it, or you will loose your time.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make it faster, you could try an alternative Python implementation like [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) or [Unladen Swallow](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/). If you're using an older version of Python, you might also want to take a look at [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks. Do any of those support Python 3.2 though?

Comment: Not yet, but the PyPy team is already planning to include support for it.

Comment: If they could get it done within the next few days or so, that would be pretty awesome, but I don't think I'd get that lucky. :p